# What kind of X509 format Android and iOS accept ? (PKCS#7 needed to be installed)

Tags: android, iphone, ios, x509certificate, x509

I wan't to know what X.509 certificate Android and iOS they support. I know they accept the PKCS#12 format (.p12), but how about others ?

I need to install a CA chain on a Android and iOS phones, with a .p7b extension (PKCS#7), but it doesn't works. Many tutorial exists, but they didn't talk about the list of certificate are supported.

And if that's impossible, do you have an idea to install my certificate ? I thank to use openSSL and convert to p12 format, but i don't know if it's the best way for.

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android, I've always just used DER-encoded certificates.

For iOS, IIRC, you need to use the [iOS Configuration Utility](https://www.apple.com/support/iphone/business/) in order to embed the certificate in a profile and install that profile to the device.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get a DER encoded cert into iOS by emailing the cert to the phone, or sending an http link to the cert to the phone.  It can work out a lot easier than having to use the profile editor.